# Renumbering a column in postgresql based on sorted values in that column

Tags: postgresql, sorting, relational-database, postgresql-8.3

Edit: I am using postgresql v8.3

I have a table that contains a column we can call column A.

Column A is populated, for our purposes, with arbitrary positive integers.

I want to renumber column A from 1 to N based on ordering the records of the table by column A ascending. (SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY A ASC;)

Is there a simple way to accomplish this without the need of building a postgresql function?

Example:

(Before:
A: 3,10,20,100,487,1,6)
(After:
A: 2,4,5,6,7,1,3)

Comment: Are you really using the outdated and unsupported version 8.3? With any current version this would be quite easy. With 8.3 this will be much more complicated.

Comment: Yes, it is an enterprise application and updating is in consideration!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `rank()` (or `dense_rank()` ) WINDOW-functions (available since PG-8.4):

```
create table aaa
        ( id serial not null primary key
        , num integer not null
        , rnk integer not null default 0
        );
insert into aaa(num) values( 3) , (10) , (20) , (100) , (487) , (1) , (6)
        ;

UPDATE aaa
SET rnk = w.rnk
FROM (
        SELECT id
        , rank() OVER (order by num ASC) AS rnk
        FROM aaa
        ) w
WHERE w.id = aaa.id;

SELECT * FROM aaa
ORDER BY id
        ;
```

---

Results:

```
CREATE TABLE
INSERT 0 7
UPDATE 7
 id | num | rnk 
----+-----+-----
  1 |   3 |   2
  2 |  10 |   4
  3 |  20 |   5
  4 | 100 |   6
  5 | 487 |   7
  6 |   1 |   1
  7 |   6 |   3
(7 rows)
```

---

IF window functions are not available, you could still count the number of rows before any row:

```
UPDATE aaa
SET rnk = w.rnk
FROM (  SELECT a0.id AS id
        , COUNT(*) AS rnk
        FROM aaa a0
        JOIN aaa a1 ON a1.num <= a0.num
        GROUP BY a0.id
        ) w
WHERE w.id = aaa.id;

SELECT * FROM aaa
ORDER BY id
        ;
```

---

Or the same with a scalar subquery:

```
UPDATE aaa a0
SET rnk =
        ( SELECT COUNT(*)
        FROM aaa a1
        WHERE a1.num <= a0.num
        )
        ;
```